# Drag and Drop получить id перетаскиваемого элемента

Tags: jquery, ajax, drag-n-drop

Есть drag and drop код:

```
<script>
 $('.block1').draggable({
        helper:'clone',
    });
  $('.block2').droppable({
        drop: function(){
            update(id);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Html код

```
<div class="block1" id="1"></div>
<div class="block1" id="2"></div>
<div class="block1" id="3"></div>

<div class="block2"></div>
```

Как в событии drop получить id конкретно перенесённого блока? Чтобы передать далее его в функцию update()

Comment: в документации же написано - https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: id = $(ui).attr('id');  будет ли так работать?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, разобрался. Почитал документацию.
Вот так это работает.

```
var draggable = ui.draggable;
var id = draggable.attr('id');
```

Comment: И не `attr`, а `prop`.